# Angular binding web api formatting

Tags: html, angular

From my web api, I can see there is formatting for line breaks etc, as below:

```
address: "11 Ingle Park Way↵LONDON↵NN15 1GN↵United Kingdom"
```

What I want to know is, how to I bind the data to my view with this formatting. So far I am doing:

```
<span class="text-gray">{{receivedRequest.address}}</span>
```

**TS file**

```
receivedRequest: any;

constructor(private service: nowService,
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.receivedRequest = { number: '', opened_at: '', description: '', short_description: '', "c_i.serial_number" : "value" }; this.receivedLocation = { city: null, country: null }
  }

private getRequest() {
    this.service.getServiceRequest(this.s_id, this.c_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('service data is received');
      this.loading = true;
      this.receivedRequest = data.result;
      this.loading = false;
    })
  }
```

**.service file**

```
getServiceRequest(s_id, cId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.servicenowApiUrl + "/" + s_id + "?c_id=" + cId)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Comment: You need to replace the text line breaks with actual `<br>` elements, or they'll get rendered to single spaces like virtually all other whitespace in HTML.

Comment: ok, but does that need any additional implementation on the front-end?

Comment: Unless you want to do it on the server side, but that would likely make it less useful for any non-HTML-based clients.

Comment: So that all needs to be changed on the api side first right?

Comment: No, I'm saying you probably *shouldn't* do it server-side.

Comment: Ok, so if that is coming in from the api, how do I add in <br> tags, as that data is coming in as one element i.e `address`

Comment: Why not a pre tag?

Comment: @Alessandro in what way and how? can you elaborate?

Comment: Try to replace your span tag with a pre tag

Comment: That worked Alessandro, can you add as answer and I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

> The HTML ***pre*** element represents preformatted text which is to be
> presented exactly as written in the HTML file. The text is typically
> rendered using a non-proportional ("monospace") font. Whitespace
> inside this element is displayed as written.

As you can find below, you can replace your `span` tag with a `pre` tag

```
<pre class="text-gray">{{receivedRequest.address}}</pre>
```

and preserve the existent format of your text without modify your api endpoint.

All the best